# SSRS: Pivoting columns

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a list of raw data which is passed to SSRS from a stored procedure. I have a matrix which then pivots the data.

For example:

```
Raw data

WeekNumber    Date
1             Mon 10th Dec
1             Tue 11th Dec
1             Wed 12th Dec
2             Mon 17th Dec
```

When pivoted, it becomes the following for the column names

```
Mon 10th Dec | Tue 11th Dec  | Wed 12th Dec  | Mon 17th Dec
```

Is it possible to have a pivot with a where condition? In this example say,
I'd want it to look like

```
Mon 10th Dec | Tue 11th Dec  | Wed 12th Dec
```

and then another column with Mon 17th Dec since the WeekNumber is 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But anyway, perhaps you could consider doing the pivot in your stored procedure as per :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

My secret to success when using reporting tools is to solve complex problems at the data level, rather than trying to get the reporting tool to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not difficult.

What you are calling a pivot in SSRS is really just a column group. You can add either a filter or a parent group to your column group to filter out WeekNumber <> 2 or group above by WeekNumber. With a parent group you could get results like:

```
WeekNum: 1                                   | Total for week |   |WeekNum: 2    | Total for week  |             
Mon 10th Dec | Tue 11th Dec  | Wed 12th Dec  |                |   |Mon 17th Dec
 20          |  25           |  10           |  55            |   |  15          |  15
```